# Android emulator closes when opening chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, emulation

I have some issues with my android emulator. When I open my device (Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64) it opens the emulator and loads everything.

Then when I click on chrome, it opens the chrome window, loads for a few seconds and then closes the emulator all together. I have included a screenshot with the memory and usage settings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2sRo.png)

I am pretty new with this, so I don't know how to check the log files etc.

Opening crhome in emulator, and expecting it to work